# Выбрать повторяющиеся значения в двух столбцах по интервалам дат

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть таблица посещений с именем клиента, ID посещения, ID услуги и датой посещения. Нужно выбрать только те посещения, когда один клиент приходил больше двух раз (три и более) за одной услугой в течении 10 дней. Я смогла достать только клиентов, которые приходили более 2х раз  за одной и той же услугой вообще за все время, но как сделать проверку дат, и возможно ли это вообще? то есть должен быть цикл дат, чтобы они входили в интервал "начальная дата"; "начальная дата+9" по группам посещений одного клиента одной услуги. ( интервал в 10 дней имеется в виду с 01.01 по 10.01, с 02.01 по 11.01 и тд)

Что я имею:

```
ID  имя   дата        услуга
123 иванов 10.05.19   111
232 иванов 12.05.19   111
445 петров 13.05.19   111
546 иванов 25.05.19   123
568 петров 10.06.19   123
```

Что нужно получить

```
123 иванов 10.05.19  111
232 иванов 12.05.19  111
```

Код такой:

```
with DuplicateValue AS (
        SELECT concat  (BookingUserList ,', ', patientref) as pd1, COUNT(*) AS CNT
       FROM Booking
       GROUP BY BookingUserList, patientref
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 2

  )

  select bookingid,BookingUserList , patientref
  from booking 
  where concat(BookingUserList ,', ', patientref) in (select pd1 from DuplicateValue) 
      order by patientref, BookingUserList
```

Заранее спасибо (sql server  management studio 2012)

Comment: *возможно ли это вообще?* Возможна ЛЮБАЯ операция, если данные позволяют её выполнить.

Comment: *Нужно выбрать только те посещения, когда один клиент приходил больше двух раз (три и более) за одной услугой в течении 10 дней.* Уточните задание (откорректируйте вопрос). 1) Нужны все записи такой группы? 2) Если имеется две такие пересекающиеся группы (скажем, 1,5,7 и 13 число месяца - первые 3 в одной 10-дневке, вторые в другой, но не все 4 в одной) - что должно быть выведено?

Comment: *интервал "начальная дата"; "начальная дата+10" по группам посещений одного клиента одной услуги. ( интервал в 10 дней имеется в виду с 01.01 по 10.01, с 02.01 по 11.01 и тд)* Формулировка противоречива. "с 01.01 по 10.01" - это "начальная дата".."начальная дата+9". Откорректируйте.

Comment: @Akina 1) да, нужны все записи группы. 2) думаю, нужно вывести обе группы. Я наверное очень плохо объясняю, ну задание было следующее: есть данные о посещениях пациентов разных врачей. Нужно достать данные  о визитах пациентов, которые посещали одного и того же врача более 2х раз за 10 дней.

Comment: Задача должна быть сформулирована ОДНОЗНАЧНО. Так что додумайте, а потом откорректируйте формулировки. Если это Вам недоформулировали - дойдите до руководства и уточните.

Comment: @Akina если имеется две такие пересекающиеся группы достаточно будет вывести какую то одну.

Comment: Не пойдёт. Остаётся неоднозначность, какую именно вывести. Более того, представьте вариант с датами 1, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24. Можно вывести 1 группу - (12,16,20), а можно и две - (1,4,8) и (16,20,24)... такие неоднозначности - уже вообще ни в какие ворота. Сформулируйте так, чтобы любое правильное решение давало строго один и тот же результат вне зависимости от того, как было понято условие.

Comment: @Akina  не нужно их группировать. нужно просто выдать визиты, которые входят в эти интервалы. В этой в выборке в основном по три визита совпадают, очень редко 4-6 и нормальный разброс по датам, соответственно таких вариантов нет.

Comment: Ну нет так нет... /me off.